# Running Selenium(TestNG) tests from Azure Devops

Tags: maven, selenium, azure-devops, testng

I'm working on running my automation test scripts (which is a Maven project 
 based on java and using test ng ) in AzureDevops CI/CD pipeline. I have pushed all my code to Github and created a Maven task to run the tests.

But when I try to run the Maven task , it is not considering testng.xml, where I have all the tests configurations like which tests to be run(order of the tests) and other configuration stuff like listener to create some custom reports. It is just running all the test classes present in my complete Maven project.

Please help me which config / task I should in add in my build inorder for the test to run based on my testng.xml

Below is the Pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    TestAutomation
    Test
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    jar
    Test
    http://maven.apache.org
    
        
            org.seleniumhq.selenium
            selenium-java
            3.14.0
        
        
            org.testng
            testng
            6.11
            compile
        
        
            org.apache.poi
            poi
            3.16-beta2
        
        
        
            com.relevantcodes
            extentreports
            2.41.2
        
        
        
            commons-io
            commons-io
            2.6
        
        
        
            log4j
            log4j
            1.2.17
        
        
        
            com.googlecode.json-simple
            json-simple
            1.1.1

```
    <!-- for gson https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>  
<build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
          <properties>
            <property>
              <name>listener</name>
              <value>com.qa.ExtentReportListner.ExtentRerportListener</value>
            </property>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
  </plugin>             
    </plugins>
 </build>
```

Comment: can you share your pom.xml file?

Comment: Hi, This is pom.xml

Comment: any update for this issue?